# C# RadioButton List get the value in JS using $("input[name='<%=

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to get the value of a c# radio button list within js. Because the ID changes and ends up having `ContentPlaceHolder1` in front of it when the code runs I can't just call the ID in the standard js way.

Instead I've used this before on other fields but never on a radio button list. I'm using this line of code but getting back undefined - can anyone spot a problem!?

```
var prvalue = $("input[name='<%=personalRadio.UniqueID%>']:radio:checked").val();`
console.log(prvalue);`
```

This is driving me insane! Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

So the overall id of the radio button list when running is `ContentPlaceHolder1_personalRadio`

I have however noticed that each radio item is marginally different: 
`ContentPlaceHolder1_personalRadio_0` and `ContentPlaceHolder1_personalRadio_1`

So I think that's why my value isn't being selected. I'm not sure how to account for that though?

This is my radio button field in the .aspx file:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="personalRadio" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" required="true" onChange="selectionShow()">
  <asp:ListItem class="radio-inline" Value="yes" Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem class="radio-inline" Value="no" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**JS Code update:**

```
    //Radio buttons in the risk section. 
    var prvalue = $("input[name='<%=personalRadio.clientID%>']:radio:checked").val();
    var psvalue = $("input[name='<%=sensitiveRadio.UniqueID%>']:radio:checked").val();
    var crvalue = $("input[name='<%=confidentialRadio.UniqueID%>']:radio:checked").val();

    console.log(prvalue);
```

Then I've added this however it causes a syntax error:

```
var prvalue2 = $("#<%= personalRadio.ClientID %> input:checked").val();
console.log(prvalue2);
```

**Code from HTML page source:**

```
    //Radio buttons in the risk section. 
    var prvalue = $("input[name='<%=personalRadio.clientID%>']:radio:checked").val();
    var psvalue = $("input[name='<%=sensitiveRadio.UniqueID%>']:radio:checked").val();
    var crvalue = $("input[name='<%=confidentialRadio.UniqueID%>']:radio:checked").val();

    console.log(prvalue);

    var prvalue2 = $("#<%=personalRadio.ClientID%> input:checked").val();
    console.log(prvalue2);
```

Comment: Are you certain an element with that name attribute exists in the DOM?  What happens if you console log after interacting with the control?  What happens if you omit that part from your selector and pull back all radio buttons?  Is your element returned in the matched set?

Comment: Does that radio button have a `value` set?

Comment: @freginold yes - update to show the code :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var prvalue = $("#<%= personalRadio.ClientID %> input:checked").val();
console.log(prvalue);
```

Keep in mind that this code has to be placed in an .aspx/.ascx file, where the C# fragments are compiled and executed by server-side ASP.NET, not in a .js file, which I am certain where you have it.

Comment: That hasn't worked for me I get: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%= personalRadio.ClientID %>

Comment: @hlh3406 you did not copy my code carefully, try again

Comment: I copied and pasted it so I didn't do any typing :(

Comment: @hlh3406 switching to the telepathy mode, I can see that you messed up quotes in your code

Comment: I'm using jquery 3.1.1 and that's the file that's saying there's a syntax error so maybe it's the version of jquery I'll have a play around

Comment: @hlh3406 please, add the code you currently have to your question

Comment: @hlh3406 ok, thank you. In the browser, look at the page source code and add the resulting javascript lines to your question.

Comment: Thank you! I did have it in a seperate .js file!